# Netty channelread confusion

Tags: netty

I began using Netty 3 months ago.  Initially it looked pretty simple and straight forward to use, as I followed the example given in the home page for 4.x series.

As I am exploring it much deeper, I am unable to understand certain events or callback names.  For example, I am unable to understand the difference between the following:

```
ChannelRead(ChannelHandleContext ctx, Object msg) { ... }

channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String message) { ... }

messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, I) { ...}
```

Saw that netty homepage examples always use channelRead, but some examples in internet refer to channelRead0.

Also read that channelRead0 is renamed as messageReceived.
If I am writing a simple server program, which one of the above should I use?

Adding to my confusion, I also see Netty packages from JBOss such as

```
org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.*;
```

apart from

```
io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
```

What is the appropriate way for a newbie to begin and understand netty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, in Netty 3.X the packages were from `org.jboss.netty.*` see: http://netty.io/3.10/api/index.html
But started Netty 4.X the packeages are from `io.netty.*` see: http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html

Now, if you are using Netty 4.X to read message use the method

```
ChannelRead(ChannelHandleContext ctx, Object msg) { ... }
```

inherited from `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` class. The method:

```
messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, I) { ...}
```

was used in Netty 3.X version.

**EDIT:** Adding @trustin (creator of Netty) comment,

`channelRead0` is from `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` of 4.x, and it will be renamed to `messageReceived` in Netty 5

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you also add that `channelRead0` is from `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` of 4.x, and it will be renamed to `messageReceived` in 5?