# Difference between Jboss netty and netty?

Tags: jboss, netty

Seems netty has two sources? One is from Jboss netty and the other is (plain)netty? They are almost the same with slightly difference.

Such as:
io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest and org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest. They looks almost the same but have several different signatures.

My question is: some sample code are based on jboss and some code code are based on plain Netty, they are so confused. Which one should i use? Why two so similar packages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343224/netty-channelread-confusion/29352876#29352876) you could find you answer, in Netty 3.X the packages were from org.jboss.netty.* http://netty.io/3.10/api/index.html

But started Netty 4.X the packeages are from io.netty.* see: http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html

And yes, version 3 and version 4 has several diferences. I recommend you develop in the stable version, check it in http://netty.io/wiki/index.html